# Access to a JSON subobject with VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I currently have a page in JavaScript that fetches data from an API. The problem is that I can't access the `service.statusgroup.name` object in the response.

I get this error:

> "TypeError: service.statusgroup is null".

But when I remove `.name`, I don't get any error.

**JSON Response**:

```json
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Website",
  "description": "Website accessibility",
  "status": "0",
  "statusgroup": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Services",                     <-- Can't get this
    "created_at": "2021-03-14T17:08:15.204Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-14T17:40:29.739Z"
  },
  "created_at": "2021-03-14T15:06:18.524Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-03-14T17:42:22.235Z"
}
```

**JavaScript Fetch (VueJS)**:

```js
export default {
  name: 'Status',
  mounted() {

    // Fetch data from API
    axios.get('http://localhost:1337/statuspages')
    .then((reponse) => {
      this.services = reponse.data
    })

  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      services: null,
    }
  },
```

**Display of the reponse**:

```js
<template v-for="service in services">
    <v-list-item :key="service">
        {{ service.statusgroup.name }}
    </v-list-item>
</template>
```

Comment: Are you sure that all services return data in statusgroup.name?

Comment: Try out `services: [],` instead of `services: null,`

Comment: I think that you have some services returning null in services.name. Maybe if you try with `service.statusgroup.name || '' ` this work for you

Comment: Thanks a lot @gaidyjg! There were indeed services that returned null in the API

Comment: You're welcome. We are for support us.